# VSCode replacing _$ instead of autocomplete

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for coding with Flutter.
Also, I'm using generators for building Json classes automatically with `json_serializable` library.

But when I'm typing _$ sign to make autocomplete

[image]

It replaces to

[image]

when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to replicate the problem and I concluded this could be an issue related to the current VS Code Intellisense.

I tried calling some functions with an underscore `_` or a dollar `$` in the name. The Intellisense always suggest the complete function name, but when I confirm, it truncate the name at the `$` sign.

I did replicate in the following way:

1. Define a file .dart with a class
2. Define a function within the class, named with a dollar sign somewhere (ex. void test$function(){} )
3. Call that function from somewhere. The Intellisense will provide a    suggestion, but if you accept, the result will be truncated at the    dollar sign.

```
class Test {
  Test(this.name, this.email);

  String name;
  String email;

  String test$function() =>'test';
  
}
```

Trying to call `test$function()` with autocomplete result in a `test()`.

The problem does not occur in Android Studio.

It doesn't seems to be related or caused by `json_serializable`.

The underscore doesn't seems to be related to the problem.

I can't provide a fix for this but I did open an issue in VS Code Github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128577).

EDIT:

It was actually a bug from the Dart sdk.
It will be fixed in Dart v2.14

You can read [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3473)